# getting error with SQLAlchemy 1.3.24 and postgresql backend

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I installed SQLAlchemy 1.3.24 on RHEL 8.4 with postgresql 13 and python 3.9.
When I run the code, I  get this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: No such event 'engine_connect' for target 'Engine(postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:

This is the statement where the exception is raised:

```py
Base.metadata.create_all
    (engine_.execution_options(schema_translate_map={None: prjkey}),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue by removing .execution_options(schema_translate_map={None: prjkey}),

This did not give problem with SQLAlchemy 1.4 but failed with SQLAchemy 1.3